# Android Emulator is not working properly. The screen goes blur sometimes. Why?

Tags: react-native, android-emulator

[image]

Android emulator has not been working properly for the past 1 month. Can someone please suggest what might be the issue. It works for some time and again becomes as shown above. Even sometimes gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I believe thats not a problem of react native here, try reporting this to google team.
ALso you can check by. creating a kotlin starter project, which will be available by clicking new android project in andorid studio and try checking there if the problem persist, if its still there, report the isseu with google team.

Comment: It's not related to react-native. But still, I'm facing this issue for a month

Comment: trydownloading a diff emultaor, or again re install andorid studio

Comment: I tried doing the two things you said. Still getting emulator blur